# Functoriality for wrong way maps

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, kt.k-theory-and-homology, index-theory

In the K-theory formulation of the index theorem one defines the *topological* index in terms of the so called *wrong way maps*. Those maps are defined for embeddings of compact manifolds $i:X \to Y$: see section 2.2 (page 16) in [Landweber - K-theory and elliptic operators](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0504555) article for more details. I would like to understand

> why this construction is functorial, i.e. why $(j \circ i)_!=j_! \circ i_!$ where $i:X \to Y$ and $j:Y \to Z$ are embeddings of compact manifolds.

Forgive me if this question is too elementary for this site.

Comment: Could you point to a more specific place in the article?  The string 'wrong' does not seem to occur in it.

Answer (score 4):

You will find a careful proof of this in Eldon Dyer's monograph "Cohomology theories". It is true for any multiplicative cohomology theory $h^*$ and smooth maps $i:X\to Y$ and $j:Y\to Z$ which are *$h^*$-oriented*, meaning with a choice of Thom class for their stable normal bundles.

The definition of the Umkehr is on page 53, and the functoriality result is stated as Theorem 8 on page 57.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me this reference. However the proof in this generality requires a lot of machinery-I would be glad if it can be done directly (which I believe _is_ the case since in Landwebers note all constructions are rather concrete)